# Octobercms .env vs database Mail config settings

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

I can set Mail credentials in the backend Mail module, and with a .env file. Which one takes precedent? Will some plugins use .env and other plugins use the database settings? If I leave the backend values blank, will the .env settings be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database settings (`System\Models\MailSetting` model) are used by October CMS itself (and maybe by RainLab's plugins, but I'm not sure). 3rd party plugins can use something else, depends on creator's taste.

If you leave the backend values blank, `MailSetting` model probably takes values form your `config/mail.php` file. If you open it, you'll see something like:

```
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
```

It means that `host` resolves to `MAIL_HOST` parameter from .env file, and if it's not there, `smtp.mailgun.org` will be taken.